# Why doesn't the the TextInputLayout follow the width of parent ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android-layout, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

You can see here that I have a CardView which is the parent of a ConstraintLayout.

[image: componentTree view]

Additionally, the CardView layout_width is set to match_parent.  And the ConstraintLayout is set to match_parent.  That all works because the CardView and ConstraintLayout are the width of the entire layout area.

The Problem
You can also see that I have a TextInputLayout which is the child of the ConstraintLayout.  The only setting choice I have for layout_width is match_constraint (shown in following image).

[image: textinputlayout layout_width]

When I choose match_constraint the value automatically gets set to 0dp and the widget ends up being 0dp on screen.

**Is This A Bug?**

Why doesn't the the TextInputLayout follow the width of the ConstraintLayout (width of entire layout) -- similar to match_parent?
Can you advise the proper way to fix this?  Is there a different value that the TextInputLayout's layout_width should be set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `match_parent` for `Views` which are children of `ConstraintLayout` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

What you're missing in your case is the `end` constraint for your `TextInputLayout`. To use `0dp` (match_constraint) you need to have both constraints specified for that dimension:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/description_layout"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I tried that and that was the answer I needed.  Thanks very much.  Never would've known to look for that without your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the layout's XML i see the following for the TextInputLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/description_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
```

If I change layout_width like the following (by manually typing  the value in):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Then the layout looks like I expect.  This seems to fix the problem.  Is it correct?

[image]